# Update page problem with Javascript CSJS code and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, xpages

I have a XPage with a button. The code associated to the button is CSJS and first it have to update the innerHTML into a DIV, then it calls a XAgent that return a result.

It doesn't work correctly because the innerHTML is update only after the XAgent execution, and I need it is updated soon.

I copy the CSJS code below:

```
var x = document.getElementById('#{javascript:getClientId("divMsgApplicazione")}');
if(x!=null) x.innerHTML = "Ricerca in corso...";

var risultato;
var xhrArgs = {
    url: urlAgent,      
    handleAs: "text",   
    preventCache: true,     
    sync: true, 
    load: function(data) {
        risultato = data;               
    },

    error: function(error) {
        alert("An unexpected error occurred: " + error);
        return null;
    }
}

//Call the asynchronous xhrGet 
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
return risultato
```

The sync parameter can't be false.

Which can is the possible cause?

Comment: your question is not clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? I'm confused about your order of events. What should happen first? second? ... can you put it in clearer words?

Comment: First I need update the DIV with text "Ricerca in corso...", then it have to execute the XAgent (its URL is in the url parameter of the xhrArgs variable.
Unfortunately the DIV is updated after the XAgent execution.
I hope it's all clear

Comment: Instead of overwriting the innerHTML, use a hidden div that you unhide while searching, and hide it after the search. The easiest way is to add a class using document.getElementById('#{id:divMsgApplicazione}').classList.add('hidden') etc.

Answer (score 1):

The SSJS code you execute in the onclick event of the button will execute before refreshing your XPage, meaning that the div will be refreshed after the full execution of the code (including the XAgent). You can use the 'onComplete' property in the eventHandler of the button to call your XAgent instead. This is a plain javascript event (client side) executed after the refresh.

To access the properties of the eventhandler (and not the button), you can either position on the eventhandler in the XML, or select the event in the outline panel.

[image: Eventhandler in the outline]

[image: Properties of the eventhandler]

Tip: there are other client side events in the button eventhandler as well. Here's a small overview:

```
<xp:button value="Test button" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="refresher">
        <xp:this.onStart><![CDATA[alert("onstart")]]></xp:this.onStart>
        <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[alert("oncomplete")]]></xp:this.onComplete>
        <xp:this.onError><![CDATA[alert("onerror")]]></xp:this.onError>
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://CSJS executed in backend before refresh}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```